# How To Remove \x95 chars from text - Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I am having trouble to remove a space at the beginning of string in pandas dataframe cells. If you look at the dataframe cells, it seems like that there is a space at the start of string however it prints "\x95 12345" when you output one of cells which has set of chars at the beginning, so as you can see it is not a normal space char but it is rather "\x95"

I already tried to use **strip()** - But it didn't help.

Dataframe was produced after the use of **str.split(pat=',').tolist()** expression which basically split the strings into different cells by ',' so now my strings have this char added.

Comment: it looks like you have different encoding type. decode with proper encoding method instead of removing a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `col1` is your first column name:

```
import re
df.col1 = df.col1.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\x95',"",x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround! It solved the problem, however, somehow it left white space this time and i had to use strip() method to clear the white space. But anyway this piece of code helped me a lot - thanks again